# Question about positive definite matrix and inequality proof

Tags: inequality, positive-definite, positive-matrices

Problem：

Let $X$ and $R$ be positive definite matrices, $C$ is a matrix of compatible dimension, and define $g(X)$ as
$g(X)=X-XC'[CXC'+R]^{-1}CX$

Prove that if $X>Y>0$, then $g(X)>g(Y)$.

From the definition, I have the followings:

$g(X)+XC'[CXC'+R]^{-1}CX=X$

$g(Y)+YC'[CYC'+R]^{-1}CY=Y$

Moreover, $X>Y>0$ implies that

$g(X)+XC'[CXC'+R]^{-1}CX>g(Y)+YC'[CYC'+R]^{-1}CY$ and $X>0,Y>0$.

I try to use the inversion lemma, but the equation becomes more and more complicated.

I don't know how to prove that $g(X)>g(Y)$ based on the above equations.

Could you please help me?

Comment: You add the tag "positive-matrices" (whose entries are positive), which matrices are positive matrices?

Comment: $X>0$ and $Y>0$ mean X and Y are positive matrices

Comment: So $X > Y > 0$  means that $X - Y$ is positive matrix and $Y$ is positive matrix. Do you mean $X, Y$ are both positive definite matrices and positive matrices?

Comment: According to the problem, we know that $g$ is an operator on a positive definite matrix, which means that $X$ and $Y$ are positive definite matrices. Moreover, $X>Y>0$ is the condition, which means that $X$ and $Y$ are positive matrices.

Comment: I think you should make the notation clearly, in case someone misunderstands it. $X > Y > 0$ does not mean $X - Y$ and $Y$ are both positive definite (but means $X - Y$ and $Y$ are positive matrices).

Comment: Do you mean: **Proboem**: Let $X, Y, R$ be real symmetric positive definite matrices. Let $C$ be a real matrix of compatible dimension.
Suppose $X > Y > 0$ (entrywise). Prove that
$X - X C^\mathsf{T}(C X C^\mathsf{T} + R)^{-1} C X
> Y - Y C^\mathsf{T}(C Y C^\mathsf{T} + R)^{-1} C Y.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
X > Y > 0 &\implies 0 < X^{-1} < Y^{-1} \\
&\implies X^{-1} + C^\intercal R^{-1} C < Y^{-1} + C^\intercal R^{-1} C \\
&\implies (X^{-1} + C^\intercal R^{-1} C)^{-1} > (Y^{-1} + C^\intercal R^{-1} C)^{-1} \\
&\implies g(X) > g(Y)
\end{align*}
by [Woodbury's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Comment: Thanks. $X>Y>0$ implies that $0<X^{-1}<Y^{-1}$ is a key step.

Comment: @tym It seems not true. For example, $ X = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 3&4\\ 4&6\end {array}
 \right]
$ and $Y = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 2&1\\1&3\end {array}
 \right] 
$. We have $X^{-1} =  \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 3&-2\\ -2&3/2\end {array}
 \right] 
$ and $Y^{-1} =  \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 3/5&-1/5\\ -1/5&2/5
\end {array} \right] 
$.